# AHK script to monitor changes to a window title

Tags: autohotkey

AHK noob here.  I'm looking to monitor 1-4 programs which run minimised for a specific change to the window title using autohotkey.  When the change is detected in any of the programs, an alert pops up to alert the user of the change or the script could bring the program to the front.

The change in the window title (extracted using the AutoIt Spy tool) is from:

`Lab - [Workspace`... after this point the title text is dynamic

to either:

`Lab - [Results` ...etc

or simply

```
WARNING
```

The 4 programs are identical so as they're running out of separate folders stored as follows:

```
c:\program1\program.exe 
c:\program2\program.exe 
c:\program3\program.exe 
c:\program4\program.exe
```

Could the PID be retrieved for each program so that the script can distinguish between the 4 and bring the correct one to the front?  Any help from the community would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try writing any [code](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something, (not tested) to get you started...

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 1 ; A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.
Settimer, CheckWindow, 1000
Return

CheckWindow:
Ifwinexists, ahk_class...... check the class first
{
    IfWinExist, Lab - [Results
        GoSub, MyAlert
    IfWinExist, WARNING
        GoSub, MyAlert
}
Return

MyAlert:
    SoundBeep, 1000, 1000
Return
```

I see that you have expanded your question with the part discussing 4 similar .exe files. If you want to differentiate based on PID, you can use:

```
WinGet, active_id, ID, A ; A = active window...
WinMaximize, ahk_id %active_id%
MsgBox, The active window's ID is "%active_id%".
```

The fact that you ask this question is worrisome. one Google search `AutoHotKey PID` directs you to the answer. I am willing to help, but not your programmer!

## Warning: If you edit your original question, we get no alert UNLESS you also write a new comment!

Comment: @user2091246, Could you provide some feedback as to how it worked out? If the above answer did help you out, could you then "Accept" the answer? Thank You!

Comment: Added a response to the additional request in your question. Please provide some feedback on the proposed solutions and the answer was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark to turn it green. Thank you!

Comment: pls accept my apologies for not getting back to you sooner.  Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction with the logic - I've leart a lot.  And the script works in as much as I can get it to display an alert on screen when the Results window appears but scanning for WARNING caused the alert to trigger every second.  So it seems I have a window which matches that criteria but that WARNING check and the PID filter aren't showstoppers though and I'm happy to leave the script as is.  Thanks again